# Cannot get a session with Facebook app? (using its Graph API)

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have really simple few lines of Facebook app, using the new Facebook API:

```
<pre>

<?php

require 'facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '117676584930569',
  'secret' => '**********',                 // hidden here on the post...
  'cookie' => true,
));

var_dump($facebook);

?>
```

but it is giving me the following output:

http://apps.facebook.com/woolaladev/i2.php    would give out

```
object(Facebook)#1 (6) {
  ["appId:protected"]=>
  string(15) "117676584930569"
  ["apiSecret:protected"]=>
  string(32) "**********"                   <--- just hidden on this post
  ["session:protected"]=>
  NULL                                      <--- Session is NULL for some reason
  ["sessionLoaded:protected"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["cookieSupport:protected"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["baseDomain:protected"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Session is NULL for some reason, but I am logged in and can access my home and profile and run other apps on Facebook (to see that I am logged on).

I am following the sample on:

http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php
http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

(download using raw URL:  wget  http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/raw/master/src/facebook.php )

Trying on both hosting companies at dreamhost.com and netfirms.com, and the results are the same.

Comment: Had exact same problem, looking for solutions :/ [*no luck yet*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session opened doesn't mean that you are logged to Facebook.

The session needs to be open in the concerned website, which means that you should add a "connect with facebook" button in your website and click it! then reload the page and you'll get your session :)

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); //array of friends - for every friend you get id & name
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I just want to get friend's list and maybe photo thumbnail like the old API does.  So the session is not needed for those?  thanks.

Comment: It is needed. 
I'll edit my code for an example to get friends, but keep in mind that you will have to implement the login button to get a session.

Comment: what about all those apps that let you click "Allow (authorization)" and then next time you go to apps.facebook.com/someapp, it will just start the app and be able to get your friends list, etc, without need us to click the Login button?

Answer (score 1):

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

When you call this with the new graph api it says the method isn't there.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in /home/pri...